# Can not reference class in java

Tags: java, reference

```
class MyClass {
   int value;
}
public MyClass test(){
   MyClass mc;
   myMethod(mc, 100);
   if (mc!=null) {
      mc = mc.value;
      return mc;
   }
   return mc;
}
public int myMethod(MyClass mc, int a) {
   mc.value = a + 10;
   return mc;
}
```

I want to make the mc as a reference. If objective-c is similar to this:

```
public MyClass test(){
   MyClass *mc;
   myMethod(&mc, 100);

}
```

Please help me. Any answer is appreciate. Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Should the methods be part of the MyClass Class or of another class? Because if they belong to MyClass the syntax is used wrong.

Comment: The MyClass below is the return type of test function.

Answer (score 1):

In java we use reference variables instead of pointers. See [this](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~htlin/course/oop10spring/doc/0301_c2java.handout.01.pdf) and [this](http://www.horstmann.com/ccc/c_to_java.pdf)

```
class MyClass 
{
   int value;

/*All methods have to belong to a class*/

public MyClass test()
{
 /*MyClass mc; you don't need to pass this to assign value the value will be 
 assigned to the data members of the object(reference variable) which calls the
 function*/       

MyClass mc = myMethod(100);
return mc;
}

public MyClass myMethod(int a) 
{
   value = a + 10;
   return this; //This 'this' will return the current object
}
}
```